# LDAP query not work for group Domain Users

Tags: active-directory

I run a query `(memberof=CN=Domain Users,DC=MYDOMAIN, DC=MYCOM)`

but it return zero result, same query if I run for other group it return results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I understand, when you create a user it's by default member of `Domain Users`. You can't see it in the `memberOf` attribute, but you can see it in the `primaryGroupID (513=(GROUP_RID_USERS))`. You can't suppress it unless you add a group and make it primaryGoup for a given user.

[image]

A command like the following can allow you to build the list of people belonging to `Domain Users`.

```
ldifde -f file.ldf -d "ou=Monou,dc=dom,dc=fr" -r "(&(objectclass=user)(|(primaryGroupID=513)(memberOf=CN=Utilisateurs du domaine,CN=Users,DC=dom,DC=fr)))"
```

**Be Careful**

1. Here french names are used ("Utilisateurs du domaine"="Domain Users")
2. on my *Windows 2008 R2* **I HAVE TO RUN** the ldifde command as `Administrator` to be able to filter on `memberOf` attribute.

**Changing the Primary group.**

There is just ONE primary group. You can change the primary group. For that, you add the user to another group and make it primary. Then Primary group will be change to the RID of the other group

Here under the primary Group is `MonGroupe`.

[image]

You can see the RID when it's selected as primary group.

[image]

Comment: so what will be the query to get users from this Domain Users group if I use PrimaryGroupId attribut ?

Comment: Sorry trouble with my internet access I complete the answer.

Comment: Thanx JPBlank :), one more question is there any way to create different primary group? also if primary group is changed to some other, the query will be same primayGroupId = 513 ???

Comment: I encounter the same problem and find here. Thanks for this answer. [The link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/windowsserver/en-US/44ecf833-e644-411b-9ef0-fa56b7fb4e26/domain-users-not-showing-up-in-memberof) said the same thing. The ldap filter `(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(primaryGroupID=513))` could get the account list in the `Domain Users` group.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's a known issue. The `Domain Users` is typically the so-called *default group* for new users. That group name for whatever reasons isn't added to the regular list of groups a user is a member of - it's always a messy special case that needs to be handled separately.

See Technet [AD Default Groups](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756898%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for more information.

I don't think there's any easy way to make this work, unfortunately....