# Missing results from Get-ADUser/MemberOf command in PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to write a script which will loop through domain accounts and print out the users names and groups that they belong to:

```
$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "CN=Individual Accounts,CN=Users,DC=royprdt,DC=royston,DC=com"
ForEach($User in $Users){
$GetMembership = Get-ADUser -Identity $User.SamAccountName -Properties *;
$GroupMembership = ($GetMembership.memberof | % { (Get-ADGroup $_).Name; }) -join ';';
$User.Name + ';' + $GroupMembership;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that for about 3/4 of the users in the domain, no groups are returned.

For example, for [User1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeaFS.png) the following code:

```
$User = Get-ADUser -Identity 'User1' -Properties *;
($User.memberof | % { (Get-ADGroup $_).Name; }) -join ';';
```

returns "ProcessControlAdmin" as expected.

For [User2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6nyg.png), the same code returns nothing. No errors, just a blank line.

Both accounts appear to be configured identically (apart from group membership) when compared in ADUC. If I make User1 a member of the same groups as User2, they show up fine when queried. If I make User2 a member of the same groups as User1, I still don't get anything returned.

I've tried using DSQuery/DSGet and get the all the groups (including "Domain Users") returned for User1. For User2 I only get the "Domain Users" group.

I'm assuming I've configured the users wrong somehow... Can anyone shed some light on what I might have done? Thanks!

Comment: Is this a replication issue? Are you querying the same controller as the one where you are making the changes? Also note that the primary group membership is not shown in `memberof`... but `PrimaryGroup`

Comment: Yes, it's a small domain with just a single controller which is where I'm running the query from. A user that was returning nothing all afternoon when queried is now returning the groups correctly, just to confuse matters...

Comment: I don't think it matters but it it possible that you are being throttled by the DC for your queries. Regardless if I am wrong on that assumption you are querying users _twice_. `$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "CN=Individual Accounts,CN=Users,DC=royprdt,DC=royston,DC=com" -Properties memberof`. Then change the inner loop to `$GroupMembership = ($user.memberof | ...`

Comment: Fwiw don't use `properties *` when you only need `properties memberof`

Comment: Thanks Matt, I've never used Powershell before so just trying to muddle through and making plenty of mistakes! I made those changes and it runs faster but it's still returning the same results as yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Let me get this straight, you want to have a list of all the computers in your domain, and the groups it's memberof, in one line, all semi-colon delimited?

ex: User1;ProcessControlAdmin;ProcessControlUser;Printer1;...

Try this:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties memberOf | 
  ForEach { 
    $_.Name + ";" + (($_.memberOf | % { ($_ -Split "," -Split "=")[1] }) -Join ";") 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Marc, I'm not after a list of computers, but a list of users. I ran your script with Get-ADUser instead and it gives me exactly the same result as the original script above. Of the 200ish users in the domain, I can see group memberships for about 50 of them. The other 150 have no groups shown (but they do when you look in the ADUC GUI).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754924/ldap-query-not-work-for-group-domain-users/5776289#5776289

Answer (score 0):

Found it! When I display the lastLogon property I see that for users with no groups showing, they've also never logged on to the domain. For users who have logged in at least once, their groups show correctly.